# SQL pivot table with more than 2 columns

Tags: sql

Below mentioned is my table.

```
ID  Comp        RYear   Category    Amount
1   1st Comp    2012    Elect      30000
2   1st Comp    2012    Compu      76000
3   1st Comp    2013    Elect      35000
4   2nd Comp    2012    Elect      50000
5   2nd Comp    2012    Comp       100000
6   2nd Comp    2012    Maint      18000
```

By using pivot i need to get the result like below mentioned.

```
ID  Comp        RYear   Elect   Compu   Maint
1   1st Comp    2012    30000   76000   0
3   1st Comp    2013    35000   0       0
4   2nd Comp    2012    50000   100000  18000
```

Can anyone suggest me to how to achieve it?

Comment: check this fiddle [See Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d09c/1)

Comment: you should specify DBMS

Comment: @Geetha,  please find my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please find the your solution in to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee34b/3)

Here is code for Pivot Table:

```
CREATE TABLE yt
    ([Id] int, [Comp] nvarchar(100), [RYear] int , [Category] nvarchar(100) , [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO yt
    ([Comp], [RYear], [Category] , [Amount])
VALUES
    ('1st Comp', '2012', 'Elect',30000),
    ('1st Comp', '2012', 'Compu',76000),
    ('1st Comp', '2013', 'Elect',35000),
    ('2nd Comp', '2012', 'Elect',50000),
    ('2nd Comp', '2012', 'Compu',100000),
    ('2nd Comp', '2012', 'Elect',18000)
;
```

Procedure for pivot

```
select *
from 
(
  select Comp, RYear, Category , Amount
  from yt
) src
pivot
(
  sum(Amount)
  for Category in ([Elect], [Compu])
) piv;
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: This is for the SQL

Comment: SQL is a language. Some SQL implementations have PIVOT, some have not. Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: yes this is for MS SQL .  MYSQL is not support PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

(thanks to @chirag_patel to have prepared a test case)

MySQL doesn't have a specific "pivot feature".
Below you can find ([sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8788c0/3/0)) how you can work around this absence (it is, more or less, cross database)

```
CREATE TABLE yt
    (Id int, Comp nvarchar(100), RYear int , Category nvarchar(100) , Amount int)
;

INSERT INTO yt
    (Id, Comp, RYear, Category , Amount)
VALUES
    (1,'1st Comp', '2012', 'Elect',30000),
    (2,'1st Comp', '2012', 'Compu',76000),
    (3,'1st Comp', '2013', 'Elect',35000),
    (4,'2nd Comp', '2012', 'Elect',50000),
    (5,'2nd Comp', '2012', 'Compu',100000),
    (6,'2nd Comp', '2012', 'Maint',18000)
;

select 
 Comp,
 RYear,
 min(ID) as ID,
 sum(case when Category='Elect' then Amount else 0 end) Elect,
 sum(case when Category='Compu' then Amount else 0 end) Compu,
 sum(case when Category='Maint' then Amount else 0 end) Maint
  from yt
 where Category in ('Elect','Compu','Maint') 
 group by 1,2;
```